# Trying to solve a challenge in Hackerrank (M-th to last element)

Tags: c

The link to the problem is given here:
https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/programming-interview-questions/challenges/m-th-to-last-element/problem

I'm basically trying to find the M-th element from the end of the linked list in C programming. I have implemented the code in my IDE and it works fine(some fine tuning needed) but it doesn't work in Hackerrank. I'm unable to sort out the problem. I probably think that there's a problem in reading inputs in my code. The output i'm getting is "~ no response on stdout ~". I would really appreciate any help on how to overcome this because i'm not familiar with solving challenges in hackerrank. If i'm missing something please point it out.
If required, kindly check out the attached link to know the problem statement.
I have attached my code below for your reference. Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct node *head;
int count;

struct node
{
    long int data;
    struct node* next;
    struct node* prev;
};

void Insert(long int val)
{
    struct node* temp = (struct node*) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if(count == 0)
    {
        temp->next = NULL;
        temp->prev = NULL;
        temp->data = val;
        head = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        struct node* temp1 = head;
        temp->next = temp1;
        temp->prev = NULL;
        temp->data = val;
        temp1->prev = temp;
        head = temp;
    }
    count++;
}

void Mthelement(long int M)
{
    long int i = 0;
    struct node* temp = head;
    while(temp->next != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    if (M == 1)
    {
        printf("%ld", temp->data);
    }
    else
    {
        while(i < (M-1))
        {
            if(temp->prev == NULL)
            {
                printf("NIL");
                return;
            }
            temp = temp->prev;
            i++;
        }
    printf("%ld", temp->data);
    }
}


int main() {
    head = NULL;
    long int M,L;
    printf("Enter value of M: ");
    scanf("%ld", &M);
    printf("Enter value of L: ");
    while(scanf("%ld", &L))
    {
        Insert(L);
    }
    Mthelement(M);
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Might have to do with the fact that you've got a buffered output but you never print a newline or manually flush the buffer.

Comment: The link to the problem doesn't work for me. Can you please explain the task, what the input and output should look like?

Comment: Generally, in this kind of challenge, we just read the input, nothing like `printf("Enter value of M: ");` But as said above, we cannot read the exact problem description.

Comment: Just 2 suggestions: `void Insert(long int val)` can be improved and maybe buggy too. `temp->data = val;` can be moved outside the if-else, as you do the same thing regardless the condition. I'd have something like this in the else-case: `else { temp->next = NULL; temp->prev = head; head->next = temp; head = temp; }`

Comment: My problem was i wasnt able to write a code that would get unknown number of inputs from hackerrank driver code. I faced difficulty because i didnt know when to stop getting the input in case i use a while (1) loop and there's no indication if i have to stop when i enter a character like say '\0'. But I later found the solution to be like below: while(scanf("%d", &L) == 1){........}.  This was the only problem i was facing then and now all the test cases have passed. Thank you all for taking your time to find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to the problem. Seems like all i had to do was write the code like
**while(scanf("%d", &L) == 1)** in order to take the unknown number of input in hackerrank. Thank you everyone for your time.